# How can C# Library Code know it's hosting application type without System.Web.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

We are developing several applications in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and .NET 4.0 on Windows. Two  SilverLight applications using services from several WCF projects. Another is a console application.

We want to put some "common" functionality in a separated Library project in order to factorize and reuse code. This library needs to know if the application is hosted (IIS, ASP.NET...) like the WCF services or is running as a console application, due to different file path handling.

Googling this question, people indicates the use of System.Web.dll in order to know if the code is hosted, using HttpContext, HostingEnvironment.IsHosted... The problem is that such approach requires to include a reference to System.Web int he Library project, being not acceptable if this Library will be referenced by a Console project with Client Profile.

The idea is to use another technique that do not involve the use of System.Web assembly.

Comment: "due to different file path handling" - file path handling does not need to be different between ASP.NET and console applications. If you explain exactly why you think you need this, someone may be able to post a solution which avoids your class library needing to know about its hosting app.

Comment: If the Library is hosted, in order to get the path of a file located in the same folder as the library/application, we need `HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + fileName)` to map the virtual path to physical path; when running a as console application, just use the `filename` as a relative path.

Comment: See my answer, you can get the application folder using AppDomain.BaseDirectory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need to get the path to a file in the folder containing the application (as in the comment on question), you can use:

```
Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "filename")
```

For an ASP.NET application, this will be the root folder (same as MapPath("~/" + filename)), for a console application it will be the folder containing the executable.

From the comment to the original question:

> when running a as console application, just use the filename as a relative path

I wouldn't recommend using a relative path.  This will be relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as the application directory.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to check if an application is ASP.NET or not.

Check the name of the configuration file

```
if ("web.config".Equals(Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // ASP.NET application
}
```

An ASP.NET application does not have an entry assembly

```
if (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null)
{
    // ASP.NET application
}
```

An ASP.NET application uses shadow copies of all .dll files. However, I'm not sure if this is possible in other types of applications.

```
if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ShadowCopyFiles)
{
    // ASP.NET application (probably)
}
```

Comment: I like the web.config method because it still works when debugging a web service from visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

Another reflection idea: use System.Web, but through reflection:

1. use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to see if System.Web is loaded; if not, you're not hosted
2. if it is loaded, use reflection to call HostingEnvironment.IsHosted

---

Turns out that's easier said than done, but this seems to do the trick:

```
public static bool IsHosted()
{
  try
  {
    var webAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
      .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("System.Web"));
    foreach(var webAssembly in webAssemblies)
    {
      var hostingEnvironmentType = webAssembly.GetType("System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment");
      if (hostingEnvironmentType != null)
      {
        var isHostedProperty = hostingEnvironmentType.GetProperty("IsHosted",
          BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (isHostedProperty != null)
        {
          object result = isHostedProperty.GetValue(null, null);
          if (result is bool)
          {
            return (bool) result;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    // Failed to find or execute HostingEnvironment.IsHosted; assume false
  }
  return false;
}
```

The reflection is probably expensive so execute once and cache the result. I'm also not sure what the best way to find the specific assembly and type is, but this way works.

Comment: Nice, like in Java, I miss the Reflection capabilities of .Net!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this through *Reflection* by using [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) method. For Example

```
public string GetPath()
{

 if(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName == "WebProjectDLLName")
 {
   //From web project 
 }
 else
 {
   // other than web project
 }
}
```

Although it is not a generic solution, you can enhance it by using a `GetReferenceAssemblies` method (on calling assembly).

Comment: The question is the Library not knows who applications will use it, as is a "generic" library for several applications.

Comment: From `GetReferenceAssemblies`, you can knew it easily is `System.Web` loaded

Answer (score 0):

Since the Silverlight and console applications will know about their environment, you could put the relevant information in their App.config files, so that the common library can access the environment information through configuration, rather than trying to work it out itself.

Comment: Not sure. I'm new to .NET, and a Console application project doesn't have any .config file by default. The Library will be used mainly in the WCF services and looking for a solution that involve only code, not external files.

Comment: You can use an App.config file with console applications:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1168194.aspx/1?how+to+use+app+config+in+a+console+application

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is create an enum in the library of the different application types that the library will be used for. Create a variable in the library with the enum. Then have the app that is using the library set the variable with that enum, and the library will then know what type of app is using it.

Like this:

```
public static enum applicationType { hosted, console};
public static applicationType applicationConsumerType = applicationType.console;
```

You could also make a parameter of enum type applicationType required as part of the libraries method calls, and thereby get the application type. Then no matter what, you always know, since it's a required parameter.

Comment: Nice trick, but the goal is the Library know by itself which kind of applications is using it (hosted in IIS or Console mainly), without any intervention of the application using it, because in a WCF project will need to setup that variable in all services as the application has many starting points (services) and can not guarantee which will be the first.

Comment: The application will need to indicate to the library what type of application it is. The library can't know by itself, because it is an individual, independent unit of code (presumably), and doesn't know about the app calling it. The app will have to "inform" it, either through a parameter, or some sort of setting, XML file (as the other poster indicated, although the problem I see with that method is that it forces the library to rely on a file that might not exist), or something. Make the enum a parameter that is passed into the methods called in the library maybe.

Comment: As a side note, the library can't know what it is being used by all by itself because it is not dependent on the application. The manifest in it's modules will not indicate any dependencies or anything on your application's files. So it will need to be "informed" (at the risk of repeating myself! LOL).